# Extract datatable column by indexing a character vector

Tags: r

I am asking a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664012/extract-column-name-to-vector-by-calling-the-column-name) except I am trying to index a vector of column names.

If I have a data.table like `a`:

```
a <- data.table("NAME" = c("A", "B", "A"),  
                "PASS_FAIL" = c("F", "P", "P"),
                "TEST_COUNT" = c(NA, NA, 1))
```

And a vector of column names:

```
col_names <- c("NAME", "PASS_FAIL", "TEST_COUNT")
```

Then try to index with this syntax:

```
a[col_names[1]]
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(a, col_names[1]) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified 
  either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as
  sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data 
  due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

I also tried this `a$col_names[1]` which results in `NULL` (but since it is a data.table this is the wrong syntax.

Calling just `col_names[1]` gives a character `"NAME"` which is what I expected.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `[[]]` as otherwise you are attempting to index the row.

```
a[[col_names[1]]]
```